# ADF - copy activity handling empty string and null

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

Currently, I am working on to load the pipe delimiter file into sql table using copy activity.

Sample file row:
1|val1|  |val3||val5|

In the file we have space and null are indicated without space between the pipe delimiter. We have specify the empty string as null in the dataset. In that case both are column are treating as null.

Is there anyway to load the empty string into table as empty string using copy activity?

Answer (score 1):

Only using copy activity, you cannot update the empty string(`' '`)  in the SQL table. You can use script activity next to copy activity in adf to update values with `' '` to null.

Below sample pipe delimited data is taken as source. In this sample, second row has empty string `' '`.

```
row_num|col1|col2|col3
1||val21|val31
2| |value22|val23
```

This second row is copied as is in SQL when ADF copy activity is used. Below is the SQL table data.

[image]

- To convert this, take the script activity and give the query to update `' '` as null.

[image]

```sql
update tgt_log
set col1=null
where col1=' ';
```

[image]

This code updates col1 values only. You can write dynamic query or stored procedure to update all column values and execute it using ADF script activity or stored procedure activity.

```sql
UPDATE <YourTable>
SET Column1 = CASE WHEN Column1 = ' ' THEN NULL ELSE Column1 END,
    Column2 = CASE WHEN Column2 = ' ' THEN NULL ELSE Column2 END,
    Column3 = CASE WHEN Column3 = ' ' THEN NULL ELSE Column3 END,
    .......
```

If number of columns are less, you can use the above query. This too updates the same.